# Python - determine change in value from one period to the next

Tags: python, list, csv, import

Thanks in advance for your help.  I am new to Python (and coding in general), and am trying to do several things, with the imported CSV file below.  The problem that I am having is capturing (in a list) the change in revenue from one row to the next for example, the change in revenue from 10/18 to 11/18.  Ideally, I would have a final list with `["month", "change vs previous"]`.

Here is my existing code:

```
import os

import csv

csvpath = os.path.join("C:/test2", "budget_data.csv")

num_rows=0
total_rev=0

with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ",")
    print(csvreader)
    csv_header =next(csvreader)
    print(f"CSV Header:  {csv_header}")
    for row in csvreader:
        num_rows=num_rows+1
        total_rev += int(row[1])


print("")
print("There are "+ str(num_rows) +" months of data!")
print("Total Revenue is "+str(total_rev)+" dollars!")
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your csv file?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have attached some anonymized data.  It is not the actual data, but is in the exact same format, including the headers.

Comment: Date Profit/Losses
Jan-10 867884
Feb-10 984655
Mar-10 322013
Apr-10 -69417
May-10 310503
Jun-10 522857
Jul-10 1033096
Aug-10 604885
Sep-10 -216386
Oct-10 477532
Nov-10 893810
Dec-10 -80353
Jan-11 779806
Feb-11 -335203
Mar-11 697845
Apr-11 793163
May-11 485070
Jun-11 584122
Jul-11 62729
Aug-11 668179
Sep-11 899906
Oct-11 834719
Nov-11 132003
Dec-11 309978
Jan-12 -755566
Feb-12 1170593
Mar-12 252788
Apr-12 1151518
May-12 817256
Jun-12 570757
Jul-12 506702
Aug-12 -1022534
Sep-12 475062
Oct-12 779976
Nov-12 144175
Dec-12 542494
Jan-13 359333

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to add additional information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable to hold the revenue for the previous row. This is updated at the end of each loop:

```
import os
import csv

csvpath = os.path.join("C:/test2", "budget_data.csv")

num_rows = 0
total_rev = 0
change_from_previous = []

with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    print(csvreader)
    csv_header = next(csvreader)
    print(f"CSV Header:  {csv_header}")
    previous_revenue = 0

    for row in csvreader:
        revenue = int(row[1])
        num_rows += 1
        total_rev += revenue
        change_from_previous.append([row[0], revenue - previous_revenue])
        previous_revenue = revenue

print("")
print("There are "+ str(num_rows) +" months of data!")
print("Total Revenue is "+str(total_rev)+" dollars!")
print(change_from_previous)
```

This would display a list holding each month and change:

```
[['Jan-10', 867884], ['Feb-10', 116771], ['Mar-10', -662642], ['Apr-10', -391430], ['May-10', 379920], ['Jun-10', 212354], ['Jul-10', 510239], ['Aug-10', -428211], ['Sep-10', -821271], ['Oct-10', 693918], ['Nov-10', 416278], ['Dec-10', -974163], ['Jan-11', 860159], ['Feb-11', -1115009], ['Mar-11', 1033048], ['Apr-11', 95318], ['May-11', -308093], ['Jun-11', 99052], ['Jul-11', -521393], ['Aug-11', 605450], ['Sep-11', 231727], ['Oct-11', -65187], ['Nov-11', -702716], ['Dec-11', 177975], ['Jan-12', -1065544], ['Feb-12', 1926159], ['Mar-12', -917805], ['Apr-12', 898730], ['May-12', -334262], ['Jun-12', -246499], ['Jul-12', -64055], ['Aug-12', -1529236], ['Sep-12', 1497596], ['Oct-12', 304914], ['Nov-12', -635801], ['Dec-12', 398319], ['Jan-13', -183161]]
```